# How can I keep a Node app running on Heroku which is not a server without providing $PORT?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've written a web **scraper** using node.js which **scrapes** a particular website, gets some data from there and then tweets it. I've deployed this app on Heroku and app crashes by giving an error that `$PORT` couldn't be bound within 60 seconds. I've tried putting both `worker: node index.js` and `web: node index.js` in `Procfile` one by one, but it crashes.

Since my app is not a server hence does not need a port number, how can I keep it running with out making my app a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on the worker process and off the default web process:

```
$ heroku scale web=0 worker=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/use-pm2-with-cloud-providers/